# What happens when an executable tries to access a .dll that isn't loaded

Tags: windows, dll

What happens when an executable tries to access a .DLL that isn't loaded ?

Does it try to find it at system32 folder and load it or something else?

Also can someone please explain to me where in the ram .DLL are saved and referenced, I tried researching online but didn't find many good answers...

Thanks in advance

Comment: For your second question (which should be a separate post - this is a Question and Answer site, not Question**s** and Answers): The OS decides at load time where in RAM the DLL will be loaded. There is no specific physical memory location; there are logical starting locations that things are based from, but the OS is free to move them to where it needs them to load.

Comment: What do you mean by "access a .dll that isn't loaded"? What kind of access are you referring to? Also, what is your programming problem that is leading you to ask this question? StackOverflow focuses on solving programming problems, so share the problem and we can try to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The best description for the search processed used that I've been able to find is in the documentation for [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) at MSDN. An excerpt from the **Remarks** section of that documentation:

> When no path is specified, the function searches for loaded modules whose base name matches the base name of the module to be loaded. If the name matches, the load succeeds. Otherwise, the function searches for the file.
>
> The first directory searched is the directory containing the image file used to create the calling process (for more information, see the CreateProcess function). Doing this allows private dynamic-link library (DLL) files associated with a process to be found without adding the process's installed directory to the PATH environment variable. If a relative path is specified, the entire relative path is appended to every token in the DLL search path list. To load a module from a relative path without searching any other path, use GetFullPathName to get a nonrelative path and call LoadLibrary with the nonrelative path. For more information on the DLL search order, see Dynamic-Link Library Search Order.
>
> The search path can be altered using the SetDllDirectory function. This solution is recommended instead of using SetCurrentDirectory or hard-coding the full path to the DLL.
>
> If a path is specified and there is a redirection file for the application, the function searches for the module in the application's directory. If the module exists in the application's directory, LoadLibrary ignores the specified path and loads the module from the application's directory. If the module does not exist in the application's directory, LoadLibrary loads the module from the specified directory. For more information, see Dynamic Link Library Redirection.
>
> If you call LoadLibrary with the name of an assembly without a path specification and the assembly is listed in the system compatible manifest, the call is automatically redirected to the side-by-side assembly.